# XSL For-each loop set variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I know vars in XSL are more like constants in other languages and they cant be set inside of an operation.  However, I need to loop through a node, evaluate a child element value and if true, set that value to a param or variable.  once done, i need to pass those parms into a template.  I know this isnt correct, but something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/person/address/address_line">
            <xsl:if test="type = 'local_script'">
                   <xsl:variable name="vADDRESS_LINE1" select="addressValue"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatAddress">
            <xsl:with-param name="ADDRESS_LINE1" select="$vADDRESS_LINE1"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="FormatAddress">
        <xsl:param name="ADDRESS_LINE1"></xsl:param>
            <!-- laydown formatted address in xml-->
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to "loop" and call templates? What is the transformation you need to achieve? Why don't you push the value to a matching template with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="/person/address/address_line[type = 'local_script']/addressValue"/>` and have your `<xsl:template match="addressValue"><!-- now format context node data here --></xsl:template>`?

Comment: Im pretty new to XSL and my head is having a hard time coming out of traditional programming tactics.   I am calling a look because /person/address/address_line can have multiple instances.  one for zipecode, one for country, one for state, one for address_line1 and so forth.  I need to loop thorough all of the address lines and evaluate the "type" element of each line.  if that type element matches my need, then i need grab the address value.  once I have all the AddressValues for all the Address_lines of a certain type, then i have to pass them to a template to be formatted

Comment: You might want to edit your question and show us some sample input data and explain which data you need together in that template. What kind of data type and value do you expect that parameter to have, a sequence of elements?

Comment: It's difficult to reverse-engineer a specification from code that doesn't work, and has no chance of working. You've basically written the code in a language that doesn't exist and are hoping that we can work out what it would do if the language did exist.

Comment: @MichaelKay - fair enough.  As I said, I don't know xsl that well and only touch it once in a great while.  let me think through your answer below and see if it fits my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that what you are trying to do is to bind the variable vADDRESS_LINE1 to the addressValue value of the last addressLine that has type = 'local_script'.

The correct way to do that is

```
<xsl:variable name="vADDRESS_LINE1" 
  select="/person/address/address_line[type='local_script'][last()]/addressValue"/>
```

If there's only one address_line that satisfies the predicate then you can leave out the `[last()]`.